# Stack from data object

Tags: d3.js

I have a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpgNMb?editors=0011) demonstrating my case.

I have an array of objects which contains an array of objects `values` that has the values I would like to use in the D3 stack function.

Simple question is how do I get the values from the data object into the stack function

```
let stackedSeries
let legendKeys = ['used', 'new']

let data = [
  {
    date: 12/1/17,
  },
  values = [{
    'used': 23,
    'new': 40
  }],
  {
    date: 12/2/17,
  },
  values = [{
    'used': 37,
    'new': 12
  }],
  {
    date: 12/3/17,
  },
  values = [{
    'used': 67,
    'new': 98
  }]
]


let stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(legendKeys)

let stackedSeries = stack(data.values);

console.log(stackedSeries)
```